# Populate Existing Table With Data Using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using the method below I am trying to populate an existing table with data however the function fills it with the same values. I can perform such action adding append method, but in my case the table should be exist already :)

HTML

```
<table class="table">
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
        <tr><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

JQuery

```
$.each(data, function(i, value){
    $(".table td").text(value.product);
}); 

var data= [
{"product":"RD0"},
{"product":"RD1-184"},
{"product":"RD1-185"}
]
```

Comment: Hint: You're looping through the data and adding every item to each cell. You have forgotten to loop through the cells.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a code snipped using your sample from above with a demo in JSFiddle.

```
$(function() {
  var data = [{
    "product": "RD0"
  }, {
    "product": "RD1-184"
  }, {
    "product": "RD1-185"
  }];
  var table = $('.table');
  $.each(data, function(i, value) {
    table.find('tr').eq(i).find('td').text(value.product);
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qur62os2/

Comment: Not a problem! If this solved the problem for you, would you kindly consider marking it as the answer?

Comment: Sure, I just need to wait 3 more minutes to select answer

Answer (score 2):

you probably need something like this:

```
$(".table").find('td').each(function(i) {
  $(this).text(data[i].product);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/fn8q8e3x/